# how to find index value of SetItemState() in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CListCtrl where i have to find the index value of

```
m_searchListCtrl.SetItemState(index, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

I have tried this let me know if its correct :

```
int index = m_searchListCtrl.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);
```

This is the actual code

```
int index = m_searchListCtrl.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED);
m_searchListCtrl.SetItemState(index, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

I need the index value to deselect an item from CListCtrl using `SetItemState()`

Comment: The actual code i wrote is to deselect(unmark) index item of CListCtrl.

Comment: You can [edit] your question any time to add more information.